# Will the Lee 100mm filter holder work with a Samyang 14mm autofocus lens?

Tags: lens, filters

Will this [Lee 100mm filter holder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E9N90M8) work with a [Samyang AF 14 mm F2.8 Autofocus Lens for Sony FE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M02ZXSM)? Which adapter ring would I need to buy for it? Thank you, and apologies if any of this comes across as confusing - I'm very new to filters and what-not. I posted on another account yesterday and received some very useful tips, but had to remove it as it was a duplicate account causing me login issues. Thanks, guys!

[image: Lee 100mm filter holder]

Comment: Ebay links are not persistent — that will go away shortly. Can you please describe the item in your question?

Comment: In my opinion this is the most succinct and to the point of the three (actually four) questions asked by the user. "What filter holder will work on my 14mm Samyang lens?"

Answer (score 3):

No. The Lee 100mm filter system will not work on your lens. It is not wide enough to cover the lens' field of view at the distance the filter must be placed in front of the lens due to the lens' built in hood.

If you are using a crop body camera (APS-C or smaller sensor), then the 150mm filters will suffice. If you are using a full frame camera you may or may not get a bit of vignetting when using a 150mm filter system adapted to fit just in front of the lens' built in hood.

Lee does make an [adapter ring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XCHBGDS) for your lens that allows their [150mm holder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XCHDRJ4) to be used with your lens. You may need an additional piece or two between the adapter ring and the filter holder. (I don't use the Lee system for any 'special case' lenses such as your wide angle lens with a built in hood.)

For more about how the Lee system works with lenses such as your Samyang 14mm and some of the disadvantages and idiosyncrecies it has, please see [this article by Paul Reiffer](https://www.paulreiffer.com/2015/07/photographic-filters-nisi-cokin-lee-review-and-comparison/).

You are probably better off (and cheaper) going with a one piece holder designed specifically for your lens offered by [Nisi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0195YKTCA) or even cheaper with a modular design that is specifically designed for your lens by [Haida](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012BH5U0E).

[image]
<sub>Nisi holder</sub>

[image]
<sub>Haida holder</sub>

You could also try to find a Samyang SFH-14 holder specifically made for that lens that requires special sized filters.

Back in 2014 [Samyang introduced the SFH-14 filter holder](https://www.dpreview.com/articles/2328058603/samyang-announces-14mm-f2-8-lens-filter-holder) specifically made for their 14mm lenses. Cokin made three special filters that fit the holder, which uses an odd size larger than 100mm "standard" square filters and slightly smaller than 150mm filters: 161 x 139 x 3 mm.

[image]

The filters were:

- ND8 (three stop) neutral density
- ND4 (two stop) neutral density
- Half Blue (two stop) blue graduated neutral density

Due to the limited availability of suitable filters, it seems to have never really caught on. Four years later in 2018 a few of the holders can still be [found for sale](https://www.wexphotovideo.com/samyang-sfh-14-filter-holder-for-14mm-lens-1594101/), but good luck finding the 161mm filters to fit it! They're sometimes marketed as 'Samyang 160 filters'.

[image]

When using filter holders with a lens such as the Samyang 14mm series of lenses, one must be careful to avoid scratching the filters with the front of the built-in lens hood on the lens. Multi-piece modular systems tend to have more [issues with light leaks](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98935/15871) that one-piece holders custom made for a specific lens do. The advantage of using a 150mm holder is that there are many more options in terms of what kind of filters are available in that size.

Comment: thank you very much. So a 150mm filter holder would suffice? Possible vignetting aside. Could I use any old 150mm holder on it if I'm trying to save money? Thanks.

Comment: @ManpreetSingh *"Could I use any old 150mm holder on it if I'm trying to save money?"* No. Due to the way the front of your lens is made, you need a holder or adapter made specifically for that lens.